# Box2d bodies unstable and does not come to rest

Tags: javascript, box2d, game-physics, physics-engine, box2dweb

I was trying to experiment with box2d as a PoC for a game project, well i managed to create the world and bodies and default DebugDraw in place. Have been playing with restitution, density and friction but could not get the desired behavior and the bodies **are unstable and keeps on flickering/bouncing** that too very fast.

---

> SEE the running code here: http://jsbin.com/qoceranu/1/edit

---

I have tried following things:

- Setting the restitution values to 0.0 but that does not give the right behavior.
- Tried various scaling factors. `physics.SCALE` which is number of pixels per meter in current implementation. It defaults to `canvasHeight / physics.heightOfWorldInMeter`.
- Tried various animation step timings.
- Tried using `requestAnimFrame`

As i am new to it, hence i believe i could be doing something fundamentally wrong. What do you think is the problem? Bodies never come to rest, neither its the natural behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step length is waaay too long. Try changing this line:

```
physics.renderingEngine.init(~~(1000 / 60), 10, 10);
```

to:

```
physics.renderingEngine.init( 1 / 60 , 10, 10);
```

Comment: Yeah.. that helped. Changed `Step length to 1/60` and `setTimeout interval to 1000/60` and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Was basically units issue,, Step need `Seconds` and JS needs `milliseconds`. But all cool and working now. Thanks.